# Conditional Probability Numerical problem

Tags: probability

Suppose a class of probability and statistics is
taking a multiple-choice test. Suppose for a certain question on the test, the fraction
of students who know the answer is p, and 1 − p is the fraction that will guess. The
probability of answering a question correctly is unity for a student who knows the answer
and 1/m for the guessee; m is the number of multiple-choice alternatives. Compute the
probability that a student knew the answer to a question given that he or she correctly
answered it.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem/2279888#2279888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick out a student.

Let $C$ denote the event that the answer given by the student is correct.

Let $K$ denote the event that the student has knowledge of the answer.

Then to be found is $P(K\mid C)$ and we can make use of:$$P(K\mid C)P(C)=P(K\cap C)=P(C\mid K)P(K)$$

This equation tells us that it is enough to find $P(C),P(C\mid K)$ and $P(K)$.

It is not difficult to find $P(C\mid K)$ and $P(K)$ in this context.

In order to find $P(C)$ you can use:$$P(C)=P(C\mid K)P(K)+P(C\mid K^{\complement})P(K^{\complement})$$

Comment: Can you please explain your answer. Sorry I am very very very weak in probability. 

Comment: Have you found $P(K)$ and $P(C\mid K)$ already?

Comment: No I didn't find it yet

Comment: "the fraction of students who know the answer is $p$..." So what is $P(K)$ (i.e. the probability that the student knows the answer)? Further: what is - under the condition that the student knows the answer - the probability that the student gives correct answer? This is $P(C\mid K)$.