# A person who does not take the drugs will test positive with probability 0.02

Tags: probability, bayesian

A sports association decides to implement a drug screening procedure to test its
athletes for illegal performance enhancing drugs. A person who does not take the drugs will
test positive with probability 0.02 and a person who does take the drugs will test negative
with probability 0.04. Suppose that 3% of the athletes tested take performance enhancing
drugs. What is the probability that…

a. an athlete testing positive takes the drugs?

b. an athlete testing positive does not take the drugs?

c. an athlete testing negative takes the drugs?

d. an athlete testing negative does not take the drugs?

I was given a hint that I can use Bayes Theorem, but I have no idea how to do this and it looks complicated.. Can anyone help me to solve this..

Comment: p(E/F) denotes the probability that event E occurs given that event F has occurred.  p(EF) denotes the probability that events E and F both occur.  Bayes theorem : p(A)p(B/A) = p(AB) = p(B)p(A/B).  Show (for example) work around question a, indicating where you are stumped, and you will receive a good hint.

Comment: If Bayes theorem (i.e. conditional probability) is a brand new topic, then you need to first explore **simpler** conditional probability problems, from your textbook, or getting help from a teacher or a friend.  Do **not** try to attack the posted problems cold, if you are new to the topic.  Also, the forum does not normally function as the first point of support for a math topic that is totally new to you.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem/2279888#2279888

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the probability tree diagram (D-take drug, D'-do not take drug, P-positive, N-negative):
[image]

a) $P(D|P)=\frac{P(D)P(P|D)}{P(D)P(P|D)+P(D')P(P|D')}=\frac{0.0288}{0.0288+0.0194}=0.5975.$

b) $P(D'|P)=\frac{P(D')P(P|D')}{P(D')P(P|D')+P(D)P(P|D)}=\frac{0.0194}{0.0194+0.0288}=0.4025.$

c) $P(D|N)=\frac{P(D)P(N|D)}{P(D)P(N|D)+P(D')P(N|D')}=\frac{0.0012}{0.0012+0.9506}=0.0013.$

d) $P(D'|N)=\frac{P(D')P(N|D')}{P(D')P(N|D')+P(D)P(N|D)}=\frac{0.9506}{0.9506+0.0012}=0.9987.$

Answer (score 1):

If you are someone looking at these kind of probabilities for the first time, it helps to first convert the data into percentages of the whole population of athletes.

Test Positive/Take Drugs 2.88%  (96% of 3%)

Test Positive/No Drugs  1.94% (2% of 97%)

Test Negative/Take Drugs 0.12% (4% of 3%)

Test Negative/No Drugs 95.06% (98% of 97%)

Answer to a. An athlete testing positive takes drugs.......

The conditional part here is, given someone tests positive what portion actually takes drugs. So the percentage that test positive is 2.88 + 1.94 = 4.82%. Of these 2.88% actually take drugs so the probability is 2.88/4.82 = .598

In proper notation $P(A/B) = P(B/A)P(A)/P(B)$

Where A is taking drugs and B is testing positive

$= \frac{.96*.03}{(.96*.03)+(.97*.02)} = \frac{.0288}{.0482} = .598$