# Do we have to calculate these probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a small town there are $5600$ people, who are older than $60$ years. Of these, $3200$ were vaccinated against flu last winter. Of those over $60$, $1800$ had the flu. Of those not vaccinated over $60$, $950$ remained flu-free.

With what probability

a) Got a vaccinated person the flu.

b) Was a flu patient vaccinated.

c) Did a non-vaccinated person leave flu-free.

d) has a healthy person not been vaccinated.

$$$$

Here we need the conditional probability, right?

I have done the following:

Let V the event that a perosn got vaccinated and F that a person is a flu-patient.

Do we have to calculate the following probabilities?

a) $P(F\mid V)$

b) $P(V\mid F)$

c) $P(\overline{F}\mid \overline{V})$

d) $P(\overline{V}\mid \overline{F})$

$$$$

EDIT1:

So we have that a) $P(F\mid V)=\frac{P(F\cap V)}{P(V)}$

b) $P(V\mid F)=\frac{P(V\cap F)}{P(F)}$

c) $P(\overline{F}\mid \overline{V})=\frac{P(\overline{F}\cap \overline{V})}{P(\overline{V})}$

d) $P(\overline{V}\mid \overline{F})=\frac{P(\overline{V}\cap\overline{F})}{P(\overline{F})}$ 
or not?

Do we have that $P(F)=\frac{1800}{5600}$, $P(V)=\frac{3200}{5600}$, $P(\overline{V}\cap\overline{F})=\frac{950}{5600}$ ?

$$$$

EDIT2:

Does it hold that \begin{align*}P(F\cap V)&=1-P(\overline{F}\cup \overline{V})\\ & =1-\left (P(\overline{F})+P(\overline{V})-P(\overline{F}\cap \overline{V})\right ) \\ & =1-\left (1-\frac{1800}{5600}+1-\frac{3200}{5600}-\frac{950}{5600}\right )\end{align*} ?

Comment: That all looks right to me.

Comment: So we have that $$a) \  P(F\mid V)=\frac{P(F\cap V)}{P(V)} \\ 
b)  \ P(V\mid F)=\frac{P(V\cap F)}{P(F)} \\ 
c) \ P(\overline{F}\mid \overline{V})=\frac{P(\overline{F}\cap \overline{V})}{P(\overline{V})} \\ 
d) \ P(\overline{V}\mid \overline{F})=\frac{P(\overline{V}\cap\overline{F})}{P(\overline{F})}$$ 
or not? 
$$$$
Do we have that $P(F)=\frac{1800}{5600}$, $P(V)=\frac{3200}{5600}$, $P(\overline{V}\cap\overline{F})=\frac{950}{5600}$ ? @saulspatz

Comment: Yes, that all looks right to me.  However, you should put clarifications or expansions like this in the body of your question, not in the comments.  People browsing questions will often not read the comments.

Comment: I added it into the post. How can we calculate $P(F\cap V)$ ? Is it equal to $1-P\overline{F}\cap \overline{V})$ ? @saulspatz

Answer (score 2):

No, $$P(F\cap V)=1-P(\overline{F\cap V})= 1 - P(\overline{F}\cup\overline{V})$$ by De Morgan's law.

I suggest you draw a Venn diagram.

P.s.  Once again, you should add the additional question to the body not the comments.  As it stands, someone reading only your question and my answer wouldn't understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: Ah ok!! So, do we have that \begin{align*}P(F\cap V)&=1-P(\overline{F}\cup \overline{V})\\ & =1-\left (P(\overline{F})+P(\overline{V})-P(\overline{F}\cap \overline{V})\right ) \\ & =1-\left (1-\frac{1800}{5600}+1-\frac{3200}{5600}-\frac{950}{5600}\right )\end{align*} ?  (I added this question also in my initial post.)

Answer (score 2):

In situations like this, it is often best to start with a $2 \times 2$
table.

You are given the following information:

```
Flu\Vac     Yes    No      Total
--------------------------------
Yes                         1800
No                950           
--------------------------------
Total      3200             5600
```

From that information, simple subtraction allows you to complete all entries:

```
Flu\Vac     Yes    No      Total
--------------------------------
Yes         350  1450       1800
No         2850   950       3800
--------------------------------
Total      3200  2400       5600
```

Then you are ready to reinforce your understanding of conditional probability
and to compute all of the required answers.

(a) For the probability that a vaccinated person got the flu: To condition on 'Vaccinated', focus on the 'Vaccinated=Yes' column:
$P(F|V) = 350/3200.$

(b) For the probability that a flu patient was vaccinated: To condition on 'Flu' focus on the 'Flu = Yes' row:
$P(V|F) = 350/1800.$

And so on. Once the table is complete, there is no question about 'Flu' and
'Vaccinated' that you can't answer.

For example, possibly a bit later
in your course:

> Are events $V$ = 'was vaccinated' and $F$ = 'caught flu'
>   independent?

If so, then we must have $P(F \cap V) = P(F)P(V).$ From the table we have
 $P(F \cap V) = 360/5600=0.0643,\,$ $P(F) = 1800/5600= 0.3214,$ and $P(V) = 3200/5600= 0.5714.$ But $0.3412 \times 0.5714 =  0.1950 \ne 0.0643,$
so the events are not independent (to the delight of flu vaccine makers).
[Also note: Unconditional probabilities all have the grand total 5600 in the denominator.]

Then you can explore various rules of logic (such as De Morgan's laws) and
various probability results such as $P(F \cap V) = P(F)P(V|F).$

Sometimes, Venn Diagrams can also be helpful, but it is not easy to put all of the counts in a $2 \times 2$ table into a Venn Diagram of two events.

Comment: +1 Should be the standard answer to all the questions like this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem/2279888#2279888

Comment: Aren't there a couple of typos in the table?  The second entry in both the total row and the total column are off by $1000$ if I'm not mistaken.  Excellent approach +1.

Comment: @saulspatz. Yes indeed. Thanks. Fixed now, I hope.

Comment: Ah I understand! At (c) we have $P(\overline{F}\mid \overline{V})=\frac{950}{3800}$ and at (d) we have $P(\overline{V}\mid \overline{F})=\frac{950}{2400}$, or not?

Comment: The reverse, I think. To condition on 'not Flu` you need to look in the row with total 3800.