# Finding the probability that a convict is actually guilty

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

The question I'm trying to answer is part d) of the below question:

> The defendant in a court case is either guilty or innocent. Suppose
>   the defendant is convicted if at least $10$ of the $12$ members of the
>   jury vote that he is guilty, and acquitted otherwise. Suppose also
>   that an individual juror votes that a guilty person is innocent with
>   probability $0.20$ and that an innocent person is guilty with
>   probability $0.30$. Suppose too that all jurors cast their votes
>   independently.
>   (a) What is the distribution of the number of votes of guilty if the
>   defendant is innocent?
>   (b) Find the probability that an innocent defendant is convicted.
>   (c) Find the probability that a guilty defendant is convicted.
>   (d) Suppose that $10$% of all defendants are guilty. Find the
>   probability that a convicted defendant is actually innocent.
>   Find the probability that a defendant who is acquitted is
>   actually guilty.

The question is based on binomial distributions. For part b) and c) I obtained $0.00021$ and $0.5584$ respectively. However for part d) I'm not exactly sure how to proceed.  I know that the probability of someone being convicted is $P(\text{convicted}) = 0.00021 + 0.5584 = 0.55861$. So $55.861$% of the time someone is convicted. Let $E = \text{event that someone is convicted}$, $G = \text{person is guilty}$, $I= \text{person is innocent}$. Now, the probability that a convicted defendant is actually innocent would therefore be the conditional probability that given $E$, $G$ occurs. This would be $$P(I|E) = \frac{P(I \cap E)}{P(E)} = \frac{P(\text{defendant is convicted and innocent})}{P(E)} = \frac{0.00021}{0.55861}=0.000376$$
Similarly I found  $$P(G|E') = \frac{P(G \cap E')}{P(E')} = \frac{P(\text{defendant is acquitted and guilty})}{P(E')} = \frac{1-0.5584}{1-0.55861}=1$$ Now both of my answers were obviously wrong. The probability that   a convicted defendant is actually innocent is $0.003373$ and the probability that a defendant who is acquitted is actually guilty is $0.04679$. I'm not exactly sure how these answers were obtained.

Comment: Possibly helpful for (d) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem/2279888#2279888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is given in the image.  You are correct in the first few part and the last one is almost correct with only a few mistakes.  You will have to multiply P(Innocent) and P(Guilty) to respective probabilities. If you have any doubt let me know.

[image]