# Two machines produce 30%, 70% materials with 3%, 5% defective units, probability that one material chosen at random is defective

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> I have a hard time with this guys. Two machines $A$ and $B$ respectively produce 30% and 70% of materials for a company, while respectively 3% and 5% of the produced units are defective.
>
> a) What is probability that one material out of the entire output is defective
>
> b) probability that that defective material was produced by machine A
>
> c) probability that that defective material was produced by machine B

I let the total output be equal to 100 units, the machine A producing 30 units and machine B producing 70 units.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem/2279888#2279888