# An example of Bayes' and conditional probability

Tags: probability

Does Bayes' formula say the probability of the cause given that something else is occurring?  Is that the difference between it and conditional probability?

*Can someone put a small question concerning Bayes' formula and conditional probability at the same time?*

Comment: The Man's name was Thomas Bayes, not Baye.  So say Bayes's formula or Bayes' formula.

Comment: ok sorry. but can you answer plz

Comment: Correlation does not imply causation.  Let's say it again together this time... *correlation does not imply causation*.  Bayes' theorem talks about conditional probabilities, such as $Pr(A\mid B)$ and gives us a way to rewrite this in terms of $Pr(B\mid A)$ and other terms.  We do not restrict ourselves to talking about the cases where $A$ somehow "causes" $B$

Comment: can u give me a simple example of 2 parts the first asks 1) using Bayes' formula and 2) using conditional prob

Comment: Now... we have as one of the ways of defining conditional probability that $Pr(A\mid B) = \dfrac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}$, or equivalently by rearranging that $Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A\mid B)Pr(B)$.  Doing the same but reversing the roles of $A$ and $B$ we also have $Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(B\mid A)Pr(A)$.  Setting these equal to one another and then dividing, we arrive at the familiar $Pr(A\mid B) = \dfrac{Pr(B\mid A)Pr(A)}{Pr(B)}$

Comment: As for examples, you may want to read from stats.stackexchange [What is Bayes' theorem all about](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/672/what-is-bayes-theorem-all-about) and problems like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem?noredirect=1&lq=1).