# probability of being crazy from jersy question

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

In a country, there are 2 states, Jersy and New Castle.
70% of the population are from Jersy, and 30% are from New Castle.
Out of the Jersy population, 6% are crazy, and out of New Castle, 3% are crazy.
if someone is crazy, what is the probability that he is from Jersy?

So I just said that $P(Jersy|Crazy)= \frac{P(Jersy\cap Crazy}{P(Crazy)}=\frac{0.7*0.06}{0.7*0.06+0.3*0.03} = 0.8235$

Is that correct?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem/2279888#2279888 . Also: reporting four decimal places of precision when input data has only one or two significant figures would make no sense in a real situation, even if correct in this toy problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

I would go into more detail than what you have shown, in order to be clear about how you performed the computation.

Let $J$ be the event that a randomly selected person is from Jersy and $N$ be the complementary event that a randomly selected person is from New Castle.  Let $C$ be the event that a randomly selected person is crazy.

Then we are asked to determine $$\Pr[J \mid C] = \frac{\Pr[C \mid J]\Pr[J]}{\Pr[C]}.$$  This is Bayes' rule.  Then the law of total probability gives for the denominator $$\Pr[C] = \Pr[C \mid J]\Pr[J] + \Pr[C \mid N]\Pr[N].$$  This is exactly what you have computed, with the following probabilities $$\Pr[J] = 0.7, \\ \Pr[C \mid J] = 0.06, \\ \Pr[N] = 1 - \Pr[J] = 0.3, \\ \Pr[C \mid N] = 0.03.$$