# Probability that all $14$ coronavirus tests are correct

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

A coronavirus test has

- **sensitivity** of $97\%$, i.e., an infected person is $97\%$ likely to get a positive test.
- **specificity** of also $97\%$, i.e., a non-infected person is $97\%$ likely to get a negative test.

**Question**: If $14$ students were tested negative, what is the probability that **all** of these tests are correct?

Can this question be answered directly, or does it require Bayes' theorem (and the prevalence of the virus in the population).  Thanks in advance for answering! :)

Comment: It is a conditional probability question easily answered using Bayes' theorem. You need to know the prevalence of the virus in the population $($if that is almost $100\%$ the answer will be much lower than if it is almost $0\%)$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! :)

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem/2279888#2279888

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bayes' Theorem says that:

$$\text{P(all tests correct|14N)}=\frac{\text{P(14N|all tests correct)}\text{P(all tests correct)}}{\text{P(14N)}}$$

Assume that $p$ is the chance of infection and that $k$ students are infected:

$$\text{P(14N|all tests correct)}=(1-p)^{14}$$

$$\text{P(all tests correct)}=(0.97)^{14}\approx0.653$$

$$\text{P(14N)}=(0.03)^k(0.97)^{14-k}$$

So the final answer is:

$$\text{P(all tests correct|14N)}=(0.97(1-p))^{14}\sum_{k=0}^{14} \frac{1}{(0.03)^k(0.97)^{14-k}}$$