# How to apply Bayes' theorem when the prior is not known

Tags: probability-theory, bayes-theorem

I'm a little confused about how to use Bayes' theorem when I don't have any way to establish an initial prior.

Say I have a sensor that can detect whether there is flouride in a water sample. Let's denote $P(F | M)$ as the probability that a positive measurement is correct, i.e. there is indeed flouride in the water. And let's add some numbers as an example:

- $P(F|M) = 0.7$ (and therefore $P(\bar{F}|M) = 0.3$)
- $P(F|\bar{M}) = 0.1$ (and therefore $P(\bar{F}|\bar{M}) = 0.9$)

where $\bar{M}$ denotes a negative measurement (indicating that there isn't flouride) And $\bar{F}$ denotes that there really is no flouride in the water.

Let's compute $P(M|F)$. Using Bayes:

$$
\begin{align}
P(M|F) &= \frac{P(F|M) \cdot P(M)}{P(F)} \\
&= \frac{P(F|M) \cdot P(M)}{P(F|M)P(M) + P(F|\bar{M})P(\bar{M})} \space\space\space\space \text{(total probability on denominator)} \\
&= \frac{0.7 \cdot P(M)}{0.7 \cdot P(M) + 0.1 \cdot P(\bar{M})}
\end{align}
$$

So now what do I do about the $P(M)$ and $P(\bar{M})$?

Comment: $P(F)=P(F|M)P(M)+P(F|M^c)P(M^c)$. So not $P(F)=P(F|M)+P(F|M^c)$

Comment: @drhab right! So then would I set $P(M) = 0.5$ because I don't have any other reasonable prior? If so I end up getting $P(M|F) = 0.875$.

Comment: If know nothing more that $P(F|M)$ and $P(F|M^c)$ then it is simply *not possible* to find $P(M|F)$. You can at most find an expression for $P(M|F)$ in $P(M)$ (as you did in your edit).

Comment: @drhab that makes sense mathematically, but intuitively I find it hard to grasp that "I know that if my sensor lights up green there's a 70% chance there is flouride, and if my sensor lights up red there's a 90% chance there is not flouride. But I have no idea what my sensor is likely to do if I know there is flouride." Is that really right?

Comment: @drhab I think I've got it now. The fact is I don't know what the % of samples with flouride is,. My $P(F|M) = 0.7$ could say more about the latter than about my sensor itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic problem. You can't know what a positive test (for a disease or for fluoride) means if you know only the false positive and true positive rates. You need the incidence of the disease (fluoride) in the population.

See [Applied Probability- Bayes theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem/2279888#2279888)

Comment: Thanks, so say we know 50% of water samples have flouride in them. How do I incorporate that information into the last line of my working? Without typing it out above I went down the route of plugging in total probability: $P(M) = 0.5 \cdot P(M | F) + 0.5 \cdot P(M|\bar{F})$ and similar for $P(\bar{M})$. Now I have one equation in two unknowns (the unknowns are $P(M | F)$ and $P(M | \bar{F})$). To get the second equation, I need to write Bayes' rule for $P(M | \bar{F})$. Then I need to solve the equations simultaneously. Is that right?

Comment: I haven't looked at your algebra. The link in my answer describes how I do these problems. As an aside, I wonder whether $0,5$ is a reasonable prior for whether a water sample had been fluoridated.

Comment: I'm also now confused about your answer. You say "you can't know what a positives test means". But I do. I state that $P(F | M) = 0.7$. I know that a positive test means that there's 0.7 probability of there being flouride. What I'm trying to compute is: if there is flouride, what's the probability of a positive test?

Comment: I think it's because I'm doing literally the reverse of the typical disease/test toy problem. My problem switches the knowns / unknowns.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare Since you've accepted my answer I assume it's helped, and you can apply it in your reversed version of the problem.

Comment: correct. thank you