# Finding True Positive Probability

Tags: probability

### Problem

Find the true positive of infected covid-19 patients.

*It's been 3 years since I've done any probability so I'm very rusty with this stuff.  Any help is much appreciated.*

|  | Total Patients | Tested Positive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sample size | 2000 |  |
| Infected | 1000 | 990 |
| Not Infected | 1000 | 20 |

### My Attempt

Definitions:
True Positive means $P(test^+|covid^+)$ according to the problem statement given.

Here's my approach.  Let $c^+$ mean covid positive and $t^+$ mean tests positive.  I use the conditional probability formula:
$$P(t^+|c^+) = \frac{P(t^+ \text{ and } c^+)}{P(c^+)}$$.

So I proceed by finding the *and* first.

$$P(t^+ \text{ and } c^+) = \frac{990}{1000}$$

Then I find $P(c^+) = \frac{1000}{2000}$.  Then I plug these into the conditional probability formula:

$$P(t^+ | c^+) = \frac{\frac{990}{1000}}{\frac{1000}{2000}} = \frac{99}{50} = 1.98$$

This can't be right since it's greater than 1.  I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: No, you computed $P[t^+ \cap c^+]$ incorrectly, the denominator is the entire collection, so $P[t^+ \cap c^+] = {990 \over 2000}$.

Comment: Why is it the entire collection?

Comment: That is how you compute the probability of any event, The number of times the event happens divided by the total number.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem/2279888#2279888

Answer (score 1):

Actually, things will be much simpler if you consider *numbers* who tested positive against numbers actually diseased amongst those tested

A definition [here](https://www.qeios.com/read/335646) says "The fraction (percentage) of subjects with a given disease correctly identified as such. Also known as true positive rate or sensitivity."

Thus Pr = n(tested positive in those tested)/n(diseased in those tested) $= \frac{990}{1000}$

**PS**

Actually, a less technical (and hence generally clearer) is applying Bayes' theorem through what is known as a contingency table. When a part of it has been provided, as it has been here, you can just read off values easily.

Comment: Yeah, the ultimate goal of the assignment is to use Bayes' Theorem, I just thought that these probabilites would be calculated with conditional ones first.  Then use Bayes for subsequent questions that the problem asks.  I'm just a bit confused on which to use (Bayes or conditional) and how to calculate the *and* probability.