# How to Apply Bayes Theorem then find EV?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

So far, I labeled two events:

A: The event of being infected

B: The event of testing positive

I thought we may need to find the P(A|B) to use in our calculation for the EV.

And then I found a given:
P(B|A) = 0.7

Not sure how to proceed from here and find the EV.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WZ7i.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem/2279888#2279888

Comment: The EV (expected value?) of what?  Can you state [Bayes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem)?

Comment: The EV of what?  What all information are you given?  What information are you asked to find?  What formulas and definitions are you aware of related to bayes' theorem and conditional probability in general?  You should have all the information you need already at your disposal.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add my picture.

Comment: Don't tests return positive if the person **is** infected? Your table implies otherwise.

Comment: Oh yes it should be the other way around, sorry about that.

Comment: Can you at least find out P(A|B) for a start ?