Interpreting this Table
I was just wondering if there was a given name to these kinds of tables? I have trouble interpreting them and would like to do further research but don't know the name of said table.


Sometimes called a two-way table or a contingency table, and used to talk about conditional probability.

I just call it "a table."  It doesn't really need a special name.  "I have trouble interpreting them."  How so?  There are $255$ people who are in favor both before and after the ad campaign.  There are $55$ people who were in favor before and not in favor after... there are $105$ people who were in favor before but have no opinion after, etc...  Notice that $255+55+105=415$

Related. May help with interpretation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem/2279888#2279888

It is a contingency table, or cross tabulation.
